# Upper bound on integrals of Legendre polynomials 

Tags: inequalities, na.numerical-analysis

Hi, 
If $P_n(x) $ is unnormalized shifted Legendre polynomial, and $g_{n,m}(x) = \int_0^x P_n(x_1)x_1^m dx_1, n>m $ then what is the upper bound $ |g_{n,m} (x)|_{max} , x\in (0,1) $ as a function of $m$ and $n$ ? A loose upper bound is of course $ \frac{1}{m+1}$, but i am looking for a tighter bound as a function of $n$. 
Thank you for your answers.